# how do I resolve backspace error in android (java)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, calculator

I am making a calculator application in java. I added backspace functionality and it displays fine on screen but when the calculation is done it displays some `random value`.

**Example**:-

**input-1** : 963,    **input-2** : 78 but i remove 8 by pressing backspace.
**operation:** input-1 + input-2.
**answer:** 14.

**input-1** : 956,    **input-2** : 48 but i remove 8 by pressing backspace.
**operation:** input-1 + input-2.
**answer:** 8.

**also if I use subtraction operation(with backspace) then it always returns 0.**

this is my code for `backspace`

```
   private String input, input2 ;
   private Double input_number;

   boolean Addition, Subtract, Multiplication, Division, mRemainder, decimal, add_sub;

            num_backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String sample_input = (num_input.getText() + "");
                input = sample_input.substring(0, sample_input.length() - 1);
                num_input.setText(input);

                if (input.contains(".")){
                    decimal = true;
                }
                else{
                    decimal = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

And this is my code for `equals`

```
            num_equals.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (Addition || Subtract || Multiplication || Division || mRemainder) {
                    input2 = (num_input.getText() + "");
                }

                if (Addition) {

                    float final_input = Float.parseFloat(input);
                    float final_input2 = Float.parseFloat(input2);
                    num_input.setText(new Float(final_input + final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    num_output.setText(new Float(final_input + final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    Addition = false;
                }

                if (Subtract) {

                   float final_input = Float.parseFloat(input);
                    float final_input2 = Float.parseFloat(input2);
                    num_input.setText(new Float(final_input - final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    num_output.setText(new Float(final_input - final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    Subtract = false;
                }

                if (Multiplication) {

                    float final_input = Float.parseFloat(input);
                    float final_input2 = Float.parseFloat(input2);
                    num_input.setText(new Float(final_input * final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    num_output.setText(new Float(final_input * final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    Multiplication = false;
                }

                if (Division) {
                    float final_input = Float.parseFloat(input);
                    float final_input2 = Float.parseFloat(input2);
                    num_input.setText(new Float(final_input / final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    num_output.setText(new Float(final_input / final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    Division = false;
                }
                if (mRemainder) {

                    float final_input = Float.parseFloat(input);
                    float final_input2 = Float.parseFloat(input2);
                    num_input.setText(new Float(final_input % final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    num_output.setText(new Float(final_input % final_input2 + "").toString().replaceAll("\\.?0*$", ""));
                    mRemainder = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

if you want you can look at the full code here

https://github.com/vendz/Calculator/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/calculator/MainActivity.java

Comment: What are the `random value`? Some random string (mojibake?) or incorrect calculation. Im not understanding the problem you are facing exactly.

Comment: random numbers .

Comment: Maybe some example?

Comment: Example:- 
input-1 : 963,    input-2 : 78 but i remove 8 by pressing backspace.
operation: input-1 + input-2.
answer: 14.

input-1 : 956,    input-2 : 48 but i remove 8 by pressing backspace.
operation: input-1 + input-2.
answer: 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey you are resetting the `input` field on click of `backpress`, change your `backpress` code to below and it will work

```
num_backspace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String sample_input = (num_input.getText() + "");
                String mInput = sample_input.substring(0, sample_input.length() - 1);
                num_input.setText(mInput);

                if (mInput.contains(".")){
                    decimal = true;
                }
                else{
                    decimal = false;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 4 buttons here in general.

1. `0`, `1`…`9`: add digit to `num_input`
2. `+`, assign `num_input` to `input`. Clear `num_input`
3. `<-`, `input` = `num_input.substring(0, n-1)`
4. `=`, assign `num_input` to  `input2`

The issue is that, backspace can happen before or after an operation is selected. However, backspace always subtract string from `num_input`. At the same time, `num_input` could be the source of data for `input` and `input2` (see pt 2 & 4).
If I key in this sequence `4` `0` `+` `1` `2` `<-` `=`. It supposed to be 40+1=. But what actually happen during the `<-` is it overwrite 1 to `input` instead of `input2`. That is why from your example, the incorrect answer = second number + second number.

input-2 : 78 , answer = 7 + 7  = 14

input-2 : 48 ,answer = 4 + 4 = 8

Besides, I have some recommendation reading your question. They are not necessary and may not directly related to the issue, just some suggestion in general programming.

1. Don’t store number as String. You do not need to get the numeric value the calculator currently hold by extracting it form the TextView. You have your `input_number` which hold the true value of the number. Take it as the most accurate source and treat the TextView as a representation only. Doing the other way round may not be a good idea. String manipulation and parsing is not very safe to do (parsing error). Moreover, it sounds an extra step to me.
2. Addition, Subtract, Multiplication, Division. A good showcase for command pattern. You don’t want to write a very long if. It is bad for maintainability. Consider in the future you may add more feature to the calculator, sin, cos, log, power etc. Soon the code will become messy.
3. Why `(num_input.getText() + "")`? `getText()` return String, you don’t need Implicit Conversion
4. `num_period` set onclick listener twise.